Bing Ads API on Linux
Does anyone know if we could run Bing Ads API with Python in Linux? We currently have the process running on Windows to generate flat files but we would like to migrate this Python script to Linux. I tried running my get_started.py script and it gave me the error I shared below, there isn't any documentation related to this so I am not sure if this is something we can do?
Documentation is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/walkthrough-desktop-application-python?view=bingads-13
def authenticate(authorization_data):

    customer_service=ServiceClient(
        service='CustomerManagementService',
        version=13,
        authorization_data=authorization_data,
        environment=ENVIRONMENT,
    )

    # You should authenticate for Bing Ads API service operations with a Microsoft Account.
    authenticate_with_oauth(authorization_data)

    # Set to an empty user identifier to get the current authenticated Microsoft Advertising user,
    # and then search for all accounts the user can access.
    user=get_user_response=customer_service.GetUser(
        UserId=None
    ).User
    accounts=search_accounts_by_user_id(customer_service, user.Id)

    # For this example we'll use the first account.
    authorization_data.account_id=accounts['AdvertiserAccount'][0].Id
    authorization_data.customer_id=accounts['AdvertiserAccount'][0].ParentCustomerId


def authenticate_with_oauth(authorization_data):

    authentication=OAuthDesktopMobileAuthCodeGrant(
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,
        env=ENVIRONMENT
    )

    # It is recommended that you specify a non guessable 'state' request parameter to help prevent
    # cross site request forgery (CSRF).
    authentication.state=CLIENT_STATE

    # Assign this authentication instance to the authorization_data.
    authorization_data.authentication=authentication

    # Register the callback function to automatically save the refresh token anytime it is refreshed.
    # Uncomment this line if you want to store your refresh token. Be sure to save your refresh token securely.
    authorization_data.authentication.token_refreshed_callback=save_refresh_token

    refresh_token=get_refresh_token()

    try:
        # If we have a refresh token let's refresh it
        if refresh_token is not None:
            authorization_data.authentication.request_oauth_tokens_by_refresh_token(refresh_token)
        else:
            request_user_consent(authorization_data)
    except OAuthTokenRequestException:
        # The user could not be authenticated or the grant is expired.
        # The user must first sign in and if needed grant the client application access to the requested scope.
        request_user_consent(authorization_data)

Error shared here:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/etl/Script/BING/get-started.py", line 72, in authenticate_with_oauth
    request_user_consent(authorization_data)
  File "/usr/local/etl/Script/BING/get-started.py", line 98, in request_user_consent
    authorization_data.authentication.request_oauth_tokens_by_response_uri(response_uri=response_uri)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bingads/authorization.py", line 464, in request_oauth_tokens_by_response_uri
    self.token_refreshed_callback(self.oauth_tokens)  # invoke the callback when token refreshed.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/etl/Script/BING/get-started.py", line 119, in save_refresh_token
    with open(REFRESH_TOKEN,"w+") as file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/etl/Script/BING/get-started.py", line 393, in <module>
    authenticate(authorization_data)
  File "/usr/local/etl/Script/BING/get-started.py", line 34, in authenticate
    authenticate_with_oauth(authorization_data)
  File "/usr/local/etl/Script/BING/get-started.py", line 73, in authenticate_with_oauth
    except OAuthTokenRequestException:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'OAuthTokenRequestException' is not defined

    [name@xservername-etl02 BING]$ [ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
    [ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status


Absent awful hacks like platform-conditional definitions and wildcard imports, a NameError won't be caused by an OS compatibility issue, so this smells much more like a library version compatibility issue (again combined with wildcard imports), or just a bug. Beyond that -- see [mre] requirements: we expect the shortest possible code that causes the same problem on its own when run without changes to be included in the text of the question itself, not behind a link or in a screenshot.

I updated a little, not sure if this is helpful, but it is related to the error I believe.

"File name too long" does make sense as an OS-specific error -- different operating systems (and filesystems) have different name length limits. I'd hash that name (see the hashlib library included with Python) to bring it down to a shorter, constant size (unfortunately, that needs to be a patch to the bingads library, not something you can do purely in your own code).

That's separate from the NameError, which is still probably just a missing import or such.

...that said, do you think maybe you're supposed to put the name of a file containing the refresh token in the REFRESH_TOKEN configuration value, and instead you put the actual token itself there? That would explain the problem. (It also means you've published credentials as part of your question, since the value of that string turned up in the exception, and should be sure to revoke them before they get stolen or abused).

You are right about this. We changed the refresh_token doing some test, but forgot to change it back. That solved the issue, but another issue came up. I will have to debug from there and see. Would you possibly know what this error is? This is on linux. I tried to install pip_system_certs and python-certifi-win32, however it messed up even more that the original script wouldnt work anymore :
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))

Generally speaking, you want to inspect the certificate chain offered by the server you're connecting to, and decide based on its contents how to address the situation. If you're connecting to a server with a self-signed certificate, you may want to allow that certificate only for the specific use at hand (and of course should make sure it's supposed to have a self-signed cert and that you're not being subject to a man-in-the-middle attack).

If it's a legit certificate but your operating system's root CA list doesn't include the vendor (and you disagree with the reasons behind that), you might add it yourself... etc. If you have a friend on your ops or security team, maybe tag them in to look over your shoulder here; what you don't want to do is just turn on the insecure / skip-validation flag.

(but do your homework -- understand why your OS's root CA decided a vendor is untrustworthy before you decide to add them, and if it's solid grounds on which they decided to do that, then maybe only allow the individual server's cert or an intermediate CA that signed it instead of the underlying root CA).

This is very helpful Charles, thank you. I had my system engineer to look at it yesterday and he didn't really know how to solve it as well. How do I look at the current permitted CA and add new vendor to the CA in this case? Say if I want to add the current certificate chain and add it to the CA, where do I find the certificate of my python script and where to add the endpoints?

when I prompt "cd /etc/ssl/certs/" in linux, I do see several "ca-bundle.crt" & "ca-bundle.trust.crt" & "localhost.crt" & "postfix.pem". I do think that I am in the right track.

The #7 is the python script I am having.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/walkthrough-desktop-application-python?view=bingads-13

openssl s_client -connect is an easy way to connect to a server from the command line and print the certificates it uses (in the format that openssl expects, so you could add them to your ca-bundle or such). BTW, often your OS vendor will ship a directory with a bunch of separate CA certs, one per file, and then concatenate them together into a bundle as a build process; assuming your OS works that way, adding another root CA is as simple as creating a file; but the details vary between specific Linux distros, so generally you'll want to look up the docs for the particular one you're using.

(personally, I use NixOS, so one adds a line assigning to security.pki.certificates to /etc/nixos/configuration.nix -- but NixOS is an oddball, most Linux distros will behave differently).
